# Find and Replace text in .sql files

Tags: sql, unix, replace, grep

I have many `.sql` files in subfolders. I am presently manually opening them up, and searching for `OLDSERVERNAME`, and replacing it with `NEWSERVERNAME`(I'm doing migration). There must be a faster way to do this. I tried using FART, but I guess I wasn't doing it right.

This is what I tried(in main folder):

```
fart -i -p -c *.sql OLDSERVERNAME NEWSERVERNAME
```

Can I perhaps use unix utilities for this purpose?

Answer (score 14):

You can use `sed` for this. `sed` stands for **S** tream **Ed** itor

```
sed -i 's/OLDSERVERNAME/NEWSERVERNAME/g' *.sql
```

- **-i** option will do in-file substitution.
- **g** implies global substitution. So if there are more than one instances of OLDSERVERNAME in one line they will get replaced with NEWSERVERNAME
- ***.sql** will pass all files ending with `.sql` extension.

Look up `sed` man page for more details.

Comment: Is there something I need to install to use SED? I get a " 'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' error. Thanks.

Comment: I already tried to install it, also added the location of sed.exe and the .dll files to the Path environment variable, but I still get the same error. Does SED work on 64 bit machines?

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS - I had to add a backup file extension

```sh
sed -i '.bak''s/OLDSERVERNAME/NEWSERVERNAME/g' *.sql
```